# How to add support for different language in Confirm Prompt (Microsoft Bot Framework)?

Tags: botframework, prompt, confirm

I would like to use Confirm Prompt but currently Confirm Prompt supports only few languages such as **en-us**, **fr-fr** etc. I would like to use Confirm Prompt for 2 different languages which are not supported by default. I know I can use fields as `confirmChoices` and `choiceOptions` to manually specify confirm choices but that would mean that I have to create 1 ConfirmPrompt for every language which is not included in Confirm Prompt by default.

The easiest way to add support for more languages, which are not included by default, would be to add them to `defaultChoiceOptions` map. But this map is declared as **private static**, hence it can not be modified.

So I am thinking about extending ConfirmPrompt class and overriding `onPrompt` and `onRecognize` method which will be exactly same as in ConfirmPrompt class but it will use `myCustomDefaultChoiceOptions` which will be non static and public field in my custom class => problem solved.

But this is *hackish* solution and I can not understand why this map is not public and non static in  Bot Framework SDK.

Hence I am asking, is there any other solution (natively supported by framework) which allows me to add support for different languages in ConfirmPrompt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was actually a change pushed out a couple of months ago (by me). You'll need to update your packages.

`choiceDefaults` is private (and non-static, now), however, it can be updated by passing it into [the constructor](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/master/libraries/botbuilder-dialogs/src/prompts/confirmPrompt.ts#L62).

The easiest/best way to do this would be to build your [PromptCultureModel](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/master/libraries/botbuilder-dialogs/src/prompts/promptCultureModels.ts) for each language/locale/culture (so you can also use it easily with ChoicePrompt), then create the object with those PromptCultureModels that matches [`ChoiceDefaultsConfirmPrompt`](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/master/libraries/botbuilder-dialogs/src/prompts/confirmPrompt.ts#L15), and then pass *that* into the constructor.

You can see how I did this in it's test [here](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/master/libraries/botbuilder-dialogs/tests/confirmPrompt.test.js#L434).

Note: When you overwrite `choiceDefaults`, you lose all of the currently-supported languages. You can easily add them to your PromptCultureModel object via [`PromptCultureModels.getSupportedCultures()`](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/master/libraries/botbuilder-dialogs/src/prompts/promptCultureModels.ts#L148).

Note: I've got a to-do to add [some additional languages](https://github.com/microsoft/Recognizers-Text/blob/7b20c1bbbfdebc3a801fbc61b094706ceebd7acf/.NET/Microsoft.Recognizers.Text/Culture.cs#L25), but it's on the backlog since you can now add your own.